# PHP Abstract Class Array Protected Properties

Tags: php, arrays, oop, properties, abstract-class

i'm somewhat new in using Abstract Classes and OOP so please bear with me.
I'm trying to make a list of Employees and Customers but im running into a bit of trouble printing out the array of objects in my StoreList class since they are all protected.
What i want to do is print out the values in the storeArray into a nice looking list.
Right now its printing out everthing from the Gets from the Abstract class, making the array obsolete.
I'll include all the code down below but since its quite long i'd like to ask the question here.
This is what the array puts out when i var_dump it either on index.php or Storelistclass.php

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    object(Employee)[1]
      protected 'userId' => string '1' (length=1)
      protected 'userFirstName' => string 'Joe' (length=3)
      protected 'userLastName' => string 'Longo' (length=5)
      protected 'userTitle' => string 'Employee' (length=8)
  1 => 
    object(Customer)[2]
      protected 'userId' => string '1' (length=1)
      protected 'userFirstName' => string 'Bruce' (length=5)
      protected 'userLastName' => string 'Stark' (length=5)
      protected 'userTitle' => string 'Customer' (length=8)
  2 => 
    object(Customer)[3]
      protected 'userId' => string '2' (length=1)
      protected 'userFirstName' => string 'Tony' (length=4)
      protected 'userLastName' => string 'Wayne' (length=5)
      protected 'userTitle' => string 'Customer' (length=8)
  3 => 
    object(Customer)[4]
      protected 'userId' => string '3' (length=1)
      protected 'userFirstName' => string 'Oliver' (length=6)
      protected 'userLastName' => string 'Wilson' (length=6)
      protected 'userTitle' => string 'Customer' (length=8)
  4 => 
    object(Customer)[5]
      protected 'userId' => string '4' (length=1)
      protected 'userFirstName' => string 'Slade' (length=5)
      protected 'userLastName' => string 'Queen' (length=5)
      protected 'userTitle' => string 'Customer' (length=8)
```

Wherever i try to make a foreach loop to run through the array i get the error:
Cannot access protected property.

```
foreach($this->storeArray as $data)
{
    echo $data->userFirstName;
}
```

When i make the properties in the User abstract class public it works just fine , but then the Gets would be obsolete right?
Should i just drop the Gets and make them public , or is there another way?
Sorry if this is a sortof stupid question but im really trying to wrap my head around this and failing at it.

Any help and tips (Also on the update & delete functions) would be really appreciated!

**This is all the code i have right now.**

**index.php:**

```
<?php
include("classes/Userclass.php");
include("classes/Customerclass.php");
include("classes/Employeeclass.php");
include("classes/Storelistclass.php");

$employeeOne = new Employee("1","Joe","Longo","Employee");

$customerOne = new Customer("1","Bruce","Stark","Customer");
$customerTwo = new Customer("2","Tony","Wayne","Customer");
$customerThree = new Customer("3","Oliver","Wilson","Customer");
$customerFour = new Customer("4","Slade","Queen","Customer");

$list = new Storelist($employeeOne);
$list->addCustomer($customerOne);
$list->addCustomer($customerTwo);
$list->addCustomer($customerThree);
$list->addCustomer($customerFour);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--<link href="includes/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>-->
    <title>Store List</title>
  </head>
  <body>

<h1>Test Get Customer</h1>
<p>
  <?php
    echo $customerOne->getUserTitle()." #". $customerOne->getUserId() ."'s First name is ". $customerOne->getUserFirstName() ." and Last name is ". $customerOne->getUserLastName() ."<br/>";
    echo $customerTwo->getUserTitle()." #". $customerTwo->getUserId() ."'s First name is ". $customerTwo->getUserFirstName() ." and Last name is ". $customerTwo->getUserLastName() ."<br/>";
  ?>
</p>

<h1>Test Get Employee</h1>
  <p>
  <?php 
    echo $employeeOne->getUserTitle()." #". $employeeOne->getUserId() ."'s First name is ". $employeeOne->getUserFirstName() ." and Last name is ". $employeeOne->getUserLastName() ."<br/>";
  ?>
</p>

  <h1>Storelist Foreach</h1>
    <p>
      <?php
      $listtest = $list->buildList();
      echo $listtest;
      ?>
  </p>
```

**Customerclass.php:**

```
class Customer extends User
{
    public function userSayHi()
    {
        return "Hello , could i get some help?";
    }
}
```

**Employeeclass.php:**

```
<?php

class Employee extends User
{
    public function userSayHi()
    {
        return 'Hello , how may i help u?';
    }   
}
```

**Userclass.php**

```
<?php

abstract class User
{
    protected $userId;
    protected $userFirstName;
    protected $userLastName;
    protected $userTitle;

    public function __construct($id, $firstName, $lastName, $title) 
     {
        $this->userId = $id;
        $this->userFirstName = $firstName;
        $this->userLastName = $lastName;
        $this->userTitle = $title;
     }

    //Gets
    public function getUserId()
    {
        return $this->userId;
    }

    public function getUserFirstName()
    {
        return $this->userFirstName;
    }

    public function getUserLastName()
    {
        return $this->userLastName;
    }

    public function getUserTitle()
    {
        return $this->userTitle;
    }


    //Sets
    public function setUserId($uId)
    {
        $this->userId = $uId;
    }

    public function setUserFirstName($ufirstName)
    {
        $this->userFirstName = $ufirstName;
    }

    public function setUserLastName($ulastName)
    {
        $this->userLastName = $ulastName;
    }

    public function setUserTitle($uTitle)
    {
        $this->userTitle = $uTitle;
    }

    public abstract function userSayHi();
}
```

**Storelistclass.php**

```
<?php
require_once("Customerclass.php");
require_once("Employeeclass.php");


 class Storelist
 {


    public $storeArray = [];


    public function __construct(Employee $employee)
    {
        array_push($this->storeArray, $employee);
    }


    public function addCustomer(Customer $customer)
    {
        array_push($this->storeArray, $customer);
        //return $this->storeArray;
    }

    public function buildList()
    {



        foreach($this->storeArray as $storeData)
        {
            echo "First Name: ".$storeData->getUserFirstName()."<br/>";
            echo "Last Name: ".$storeData->getUserLastName()."<br/>";
            echo "Is a: ".$storeData->getUserTitle()."<br/>";
            echo "<br/>";
        }

        /*
        //ERROR : Cannot access protected property Employee::$userFirstName 
       foreach($this->storeArray as $storeData)
        {
            echo "First Name: ".$storeData->userFirstName."<br/>";
            echo "Last Name: ".$storeData->userLastName."<br/>";
            echo "Is a: ".$storeData->userTitle."<br/>";
            echo "<br/>";
        }
        */
    }

     public function delete()
     {

     }

     public function update()
     {

     }
 }
```

Comment: In your `Storelistclass.php` file, you currently have two versions of the loop. The commented out loop is the one which doesn't work - but the uncommented loop is just fine. Calling those properties via their public `getUserWhatever()` methods is exactly how you should be doing this, rather than modifying the underlying `abstract User` to make them `public` properties.  Is there something you don't like about using those getter methods in `buildList()`?

Comment: I would _not_ make them `public`, but keep everything just as you have it. You say "_Right now its printing out everthing from the Gets from the Abstract class, making the array obsolete_" -- I'm not sure in what you you see the array as obsolete. The StoreList keeps a list of customers & employees internally; that seems fine.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Thank u for your reply , My teacher mentioned using an array (Not sure if its for printing it out though he did not say) , but wouldn't i need to use the array for the now empty update/delete functions in the Storelist class?
And if i cant access the properties from the array for printing, i also wouldn't be able to edit/delete them (My thought process) .

Comment: You _can_ use the array in the `update()/delete()` methods - I assumed `delete()` was intended to remove users from the array.  If you want to modify user properties, you can do so with the `setUserWhatever()` methods inside the StoreList class - you don't need to write directly to the properties because the setters handle it for you.  So still, everything you have now pretty much looks okay to me.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Hmm okay , but how would i go about doing that?
Since i cant access the array properties im at a loss.
Maybe im just confusing myself here , hehe.

Comment: You can access `$list->storeArray` since the array is a public property. So from index.php, array members could be modified like `$list->storeArray[2]->setUserLastName('Jones');` ... that would set the last name of `$customerThree` from outside. Also possible inside the StoreList class with `$this->storeArray[2]->setUserLastName('Jones');`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I would like to thank u very much for your time and amazing explanation this helped me alot , unfortunately i cant mark a comment as an answer can i?

Comment: No you can't mark a comment, but I'll summarize it as a proper answer below. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to actually make use of the getter methods (`getUserWhatever()`) that you have gone to the trouble of defining.  By keeping them as they are with `protected` visibility, it is not possible to modify them aside from with the `setUserWhatever()` methods you've defined, so you could do additional validation (like prevent non-empty values) and throw exceptions on invalid data, for example.  So it is useful that they are not directly mutable from outside the class as `public` properties would be.

In your `Storelist` class, you have defined the `$storeArray` property with `public` visibility, which means you can read it outside the class in `index.php`.  Since you are adding `Employee` or `Customer` objects to that array, those objects are still individually addressable by their array keys on `$list->storeArray`.  So to modify a last name for example, you could use

```
// Set the 3rd user's last name
$list->storeArray[2]->setUserLastName('Jones');
```

Likewise, the same is possible using `$this` inside the `Storelist` class:

```
// Inside Storelist
$this->storeArray[2]->setUserLastName('Jones');
```

So you're pretty much on track already with the layout of these classes.  There is one additional thing I could suggest; since you have already created methods to add `Customer` or `Employee` objects to `Storelist::$storeArray` with method calls, as opposed to directly modifying the array:

```
// You're doing this:
$list = new Storelist($employeeOne);
$list->addCustomer($customerOne);

// And not this (directly modifying storeArray):
$list = new Storelist($employeeOne);
$list->storeArray[] = $customerOne
```

...then consider also defining `Storelist::$storeArray` as a `protected` property so that you can *only* write to it with its setter methods. Then you also need to create a getter method that returns the array.

```
class Storelist
{
    // This becomes protected
    protected $storeArray = [];

    // So you need a getter:
    public function getStoreArray()
    {
       return $this->storeArray;
    }
    // etc...
}
```

To modify the array from `index.php` then, you can no longer directly read its elements. Instead you call its getter method:

```
// You can't do this:
$list->storeArray[2]->setUserLastName('Jones');

// Instead do it via the getter:
$list->getStoreArray()[2]->setUserLastName('Jones');
```

(Note, the `()[2]` syntax above requires PHP 5.4+)